# Loading object detection model in visual studio ml.net

Tags: ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

net and to machine learning in general. I've been trying to load an object detection model on my local gpu but it tells me to load a vott json.

now I've downloaded the program and did all the steps excluding tagging all the hundreds of images that I have. Instead, I changed the asset state in the export setting to all images. Is that bad? because when I tried to load the exported vott json into visual studio it didn't do anything. it didn't even show me an error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.